# Why is this optimization problem nonconvex: ${\min}_{x \in \mathbb{C}^n} \ x^* A x \ $s.t.$|b^* x|^2 \geq 1$, $A \succeq 0$, and $b \in \mathbb{C}^n$?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

Given problem,

\begin{align}
\text{minimize}_{x \in \mathbb{C}^n} \quad &  x^* A x \\
\text{subject to }\quad & |b^* x|^2 \geq 1 \ ,\\
\end{align}
where $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} \succeq 0$ and $b \in \mathbb{C}^n$ are known. Also, $(\cdot)^*$ means complex conjugate and transpose operation.

> **Question**: Why is this problem nonconvex?

---

**My arguments**:

1. The objective function is convex because it's a quadratic problem with positive definite matrix $A$ (or can be shown convex via computing Hessian which will be $A$ matrix)
2. I suspect that the constraint is nonconvex.  My thinking is that if we take a scalar case and real-valued, say $b = 1$, then $|x|^2 \geq 1 \Rightarrow x \geq 1; x \leq -1$. It means the set formed by such constraint would be nonconvex. Is it correct? If my thinking is correct, then can we prove it rigorously?

Comment: Rewrite the constraint as follows $$1 - \mathrm x^* \mathrm b \, \mathrm b^* \mathrm x \leq 0$$ Is matrix $- \mathrm b \, \mathrm b^*$ positive semidefinite?

Comment: Aha, this a nice way to consider, Rodrigo. Thank you.

No, it won't be positive definite (it has one non-zero negative eigenvalue). Am I not correct?

Comment: Indeed, you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless $b=0$ the feasible set is non-empty: large enough scalar multiples of $b$ are in it.
If $x$ is in the feasible set, so is $-x$.  But the $0$ vector is not, even though  it is a convex combination of $x$ and $-x$.  So the feasible set is not convex.